# listen listbox binding finish event

Tags: wpf

I have a simple listbox that displays some images retracted from a folder on my pc. If the image files are a lot, is there a way for me to display a loading image till the binding of the items are done, so the user doesnt think that the app has crashed or stuck somewhere?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

You load listbox items in a background worker (new thread). For example if you are loading data in your form load then you run your background worker. In your background worker you load items to the listbox. This will make sure that your UI remains responsive. And you can show your listbox items while they are being loaded one by one or at the end of loading (depends on your implementation).

Answer (score 0):

There is a similiar question here on SO [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655850/a-loading-screen-for-a-c-sharp-wpf-listbox) where it is suggested to use a BackGroundWorker to do the loading without blocking the UI and to visualize the loading by using an adorner. 
An Good example for this would be this tutorial: [Loading Wait Adorner](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57984/WPF-Loading-Wait-Adorner)